# Undefined method in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Ruby version 2.15
Rails version 4.2.15
```

In my app/views/organizations/index.html.erb, I have:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "org_name", "Organization" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "city", "City" %></th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```

In my app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
include ApplicationHelper
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction  

private
  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:sort_direction]) ?  params[:sort_direction] : "asc"
  end
  def sort_column
    Organization.column_names.include?(params[:sort_order]) ? params[:sort_order] : "org_name"
  end
```

In my app/helpers/application_helper.rb, I have the following:

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == params[:sort_order] && params[:sort_direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort_order => column, :sort_direction => direction
  end
```

When I click on the column head (Organization), I get an error message:

```
undefined method 'sortable'
```

and it points to app/views/index.html.erb

What am I doing wrong?

## Clarification:

This works fine if I put the sortable method in organizations_helper.rb, but the point of putting it in application_helper.rb is that it could be available to other models as well (I have a couple of other models where I can use this functionality)

Comment: I believe you should make : sort_column and :sort_direction before actions rather than helper methods in application controller

Comment: What do you mean by points to? Which line does it say the error occurred on ?

Comment: It occurs on the first line of where sortable is called in app/views/organizations/index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

In `organizations_controller.rb`, replace `include ApplicationHelper` with `add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)` to make it available in your template.

Comment: OK I put your actual code up in an (otherwise) empty Rails app and it worked fine (I routed root to `organizations#index`).  I wonder if there is something else in your environment which is interfering.

Comment: possibly. I've used this code previously and it worked fine. It's working if I put it in the organizations helper. This is why I am a bit puzzled